# PHP access path

Tags: php, apache

I configigurate 'htdocs' to be localhost/Workspace/ in httpd.conf. When i go to url localhost/index.php everything is okey, but when i am trying to connect to localhost/_members/register i get the following problem.

*Warning: require_once(core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace_members\register.php on line 2
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'core/init.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace_members\register.php on line 2*

When i remove the files form 'Workspace/_members' and move them to 'Workspace' directory, everything is working. You can see my code [HERE](https://github.com/diyanbogdanov/Workspace/).

If you have any suggestions please help me. :)

Comment: This is the solution
`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` used on files in '_members' direcotry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your **index.php** you could try it out:

```
<?php

$rootpath =  dirname(__FILE__);
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $rootpath);

include 'header.php';
include 'footer.php';
```

Also:
rename **core/Init.php** to core/init.php;
No there's any **functions/functions.php** (referenced on core/init.php line 26);

Comment: Your answer help me to find the solution. I used `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` on files in _'members'_ directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'core' directory is one directory above your '_members' directory. Try `require_once('../core/init.php')`.

Comment: I tried it but i get this


"Warning: require_once(functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\core\Init.php on line 24"

"Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'functions/sanitize.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\core\Init.php on line 24"

And when i change this "functions/sanitize.php" to this "../functions/sanitize.php" I can not access it from "localhost/index.php"

Comment: You need to make sure that your requires are referencing the right directories. In Init.php: `require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';
require_once '../functions/functions.php';`

Comment: But when i do this i can not access this files from 'localhost/index.php' and the become usable only for '_members' directory.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. I don'y understanding how you're accessing them from index.php in the first place. Are you copying the files and moving them into that directory?